# Image intensity appears higher in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a 2D DICOM images that appears (as it should do) to have a high intensity center, with the outside area having an intensity that approaches zero. When I load and view in MATLAB R2021b:

```
img=dicomread('image.dcm');
imshow(img);
```

The intensity appears much higher. I worry that this has affected the actual pixel intensity values and isn't just `imshow` trying to increase visibility. Has anyone any ideas how to get rid of this correction?

Regular image

[image: Regular image],

Image in MATLAB

[image: Image in MATLAB]

Comment: It looks like your initial image doesn't use up all of the bandwidth on the gray scale, whereas MATLAB does. In what format is your image? uint8? You'll need to rescale according to whatever your maximum is, which should be contained within the original image.

Comment: `imshow()` will scale from 0-1 or from 0-255 automatically. Do e.g. `imshow(img,[])` for min-max scalling, or simply `imshow(img,[value_low, value_high])` for manual scaling. This is just a problem of you visualizing differently. There is no correction. Remember that an image, particularly a medical one, is not an "image". Its a scalar field. Its a matrix of values. When you visualize, you need to make sure you scale it up accordingly for visualization in the same way you need to scale when you plot a simple `plot()`

Comment: Are the two images labeled wrong in your post? Your description doesn't match what I see.

Comment: It would also help if you indicated how the "regular" image was created.

Comment: One other thing to note is that dicomread only reads the image portion of the DICOM file.  DICOM files also have a header which can contain a rescale slope (0028|1053) and rescale intercept (0028|1052) which is a linear transform.  `header = dicominfo('image.dcm');` will load the image header and you should check if these tags have a value for your image and scale accordingly for display.  This is most common in calculated images but can appear in other cases depending on how the images are created.